# Python - Pivot a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot

I scraped a website and got the data into a .csv worksheet.

The structure of which is as follows:
[image]

product name, description and trade names are numbered till 30

I can't figure out how to write a code in python to restructure this table into:
[image]

Comment: Can you show some actual data (in text so we can copy it) and the desired output?

Comment: Use [tag:pandas]. See the existing 211 [\[pandas\] questions on wide-to-long](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpandas%5D+wide-to-long+is%3Aquestion). And see the [doc on `pandas.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) and `melt`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to provide a simple solution but not sure if this is the optimal way to do it.

Try the below steps:

1 - Load the data into a dataframe

Get the values of "Disease Name" column as a separate variable

```
d = data["Disease_Name"]
```

2 - Take a transpose of the dataframe

```
p = data.T
```

3 - Delete the first row with Disease Name index and rename the column with Disease name values from Step 1

```
p = p.rename(columns = d)
```

Could help with better solution, if you could share the actual dataset. But as of now, this method did the job.